# Check for length of string in UITextField while typing

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have two UITextView in View Controller. Max length text of each text have to be 4 chars.
When I put 4 chars in first text field I have to go over to second text view,
and when I put 4 chars in second text view I have to run some function.

I use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` of `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (textField == firstText){
            var text = firstText.text as NSString
            if (text.length == 4){
                secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        if (textField == secondText){
            var text = secondText.text as NSString
            if (text.length == 4){
                successAction()
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But now I have a problem: When I have 4 chars in first text field I have presses 5ft do run this delegate function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what do you mean,but you need to check the reference to the object itself using "===",and not the value,because you can have the same text in both text fields(and the other properties that the text field has)."==" checks the values.

Also, make sure that both text fields have the delegate set

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField === firstText{
            var text = firstText.text as NSString
            if (text.length == 4){
                secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        if textField === secondText{
            var text = secondText.text as NSString
            if (text.length == 4){
                seccessAction()
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for tip. It is good one
I put 4 chars in first text field. When i put 4ft char i what to jump to second text field automatically.

Comment: It's unlikely that `==` will ever return true for two text fields that are actually different... they'd have to have the same `frame` on top of everything else (which means only one is visible)... **BUT**, recommending `===` is definitely correct, guarantees there is never a mistake, **AND** is probably more efficient (you're only comparing a single pointer instead of several text field fields, depending on `UITextField`'s implementation of `==`... which could actually just be identical to `===`...).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` which is asking if text in string should be updated. So, the text hasn't been updated yet. Find new string with these new characters and then check for it's length.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var newString = textField.text.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range.toRange(textField.text), withString: string) as NString
    if (textField == firstText){
        if newString.length == 4 {
            secondText.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    if (textField == secondText){
        if newString.length == 4{
            successAction()
        }
    }

    return true
}


extension NSRange {
    func toRange(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let startIndex = advance(string.startIndex, location)
        let endIndex = advance(startIndex, length)

        return startIndex..<endIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated answer a bit. 
Check what's the value of newString by placing breakpoint at third line.

Comment: Still. I have problem with range.toRange(textFiled.text)

Comment: Cannot invoke 'toRange' with argument list of type (String!)

Comment: Thanks. now it works. But i yet have no solution for my problem.

Comment: Is  newString.length == 4 not giving true?
I would suggest removing `as NString` and using count(newString) instead of newString.length